# My app causes error when all windows apps try to use TCP socket - getting "operation on a socket could not be performed because..." (0x2747) error

Tags: c++, windows, networking, tcp

After an application I wrote was running for a while all TCP communication stopped to work (couldn't create new sockets). Creating a new socket cause "An operation on socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full" error.

I read across the internet that it seems that I caused windows to use all the "ephemeral" ports, but when I check using "netstat -a" I don't see "hundereds" of open sockets.

The application is a TCP client/server.

I've been trying to think over and over what could cause this issue, but I'm really stuck...
Any help from anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ephemeral ports have few limitations: can only be 4000 unique connections from a client machine to a remote service at one time (TIME_WAIT).
TIME_WAIT is usually configured to be 240 seconds.
You could have only 4000 connections per 240 second.

Comment: The problem occurred by a library I used called "tracetool" from codeproject. I used it to produce traces instead of debugview, but it seems that if there is no tracetool viewer than it tries to connect infinitely without stopping which causes the system to exhaust all of its ephemeral ports.

Answer (score 0):

You may have used up all the socket buffer space. Are you using large socket buffers?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @EJP, the socket buffers should be a few megabytes...
Is there a tool to check the size of the socket being used by a process?

Comment: You can get the socket buffers sizes for a socket via getsockopt().